# Replacement of characters in a string

Tags: string, r, replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ignore escape characters (backslashes) in R strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685737/ignore-escape-characters-backslashes-in-r-strings)

I want to replace "\" in a string by "/" in a string. For example, the initial string is "d:\temp\1.txt" and I want to have "d:/temp/1.txt". I tried with `gsub` but it is not working as I want. However, if I do a simpler exercise

```
> gsub("a", "b", "banana")
[1] "bbnbnb"
```

It is working fine. Are there some tricks working with the special characters "/" and "\"?

Comment: What happens if you call `cat(yourstring)`?  That way you can see exactly how R is interpreting the input.  Be careful though, because the string you have in your code will very likely be different than the result from pasting the string you've provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Paul, this wont work - see the R for Windows FAQ.

see what R does with the backslashes:

```
a <- "d:\temp\1.txt"
cat(a)
# d:      emp.txt
```

escaping like..

```
gsub("\\", "/", a)
Fehler in gsub("\\", "/", a) : 
  ungültiger regulärer Ausdruck '\', Grund 'Trailing backslash'
```

..does not work..

this would work:

```
b <- "d:\\temp\\1.txt"
cat(b)
# d:\temp\1.txt
gsub("\\\\", "/", b)
# "d:/temp/1.txt"
```