# Is there a way to make R strings verbatim (not escaped)?

Tags: r, character, literals

Typical example:

```
path <- "C:/test/path" # great
path <- "C:\\test\\path" # also great
path <- "C:\test\path"
```

Error: '\p' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""C:\test\p"

(of course - \t is actually an escape character.)

Is there any mark that can be used to treat the string as verbatim? Or can it be coded?

It would be really useful when copy/pasting path names in Windows...

Comment: Possibly same as [this Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685737/ignore-escape-characters-backslashes-in-r-strings)

Comment: Is there a way to prevent an R string to consider backslash as the start of an escape character? (In my use case, I need to prevent a file read and print from showing an error because there is a backslash followed by some character in the text)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

R 4.0.0 introduces raw strings:

```
dir <- r"(c:\Program files\R)"
```

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Quotes.html

https://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2020/04/r-400-is-released.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use scan ( but only in interactive session -- not in source)

Like

```
path=scan(what="",allowEscapes=F,nlines=1)
C:\test\path
print(path)
```

And then
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> ++ <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
give you result

But not work in function or source :

```
{
path=scan(what="character",allowEscapes=F,nlines=1)
C:\test\path
print(path)
}
```

throw error

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `readline()` or `scan(what = "charactor")`, both **work in terminal, not script or function**:

1.`readline()`:

```
> path <- readline()
C:\test\path #paste your path, ENTER
> path
[1] "C:\\test\\path"
```

2.`scan(what = "charactor")`:

```
> path = scan(what = "character")
1: C:\test\path #paste, ENTER
2: #ENTER
#Read 1 item
> path
[1] "C:\\test\\path"
```

**EDIT:**

Try this:

1.Define a function `getWindowsPath()`:

```
> getWindowsPath <- function() #define function 
  {
    return(scan(file = "clipboard", what = "character"))
  }
```

2.Copy `windows path` using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>:

```
#CTRL+C: C:\test\path  
> getWindowsPath()
#Read 1 item
[1] "C:\\test\\path"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are copying and pasting in windows, you can set up a file connection to the clipboard.  Then you can use `scan` to read from it, with `allowEscapes` turned off.  However, Windows allows spaces in file paths, and scan doesn't understand that, so you have to wrap the result in `paste0` with `collapse` set to a 0-length character string.

```
x = file(description = "clipboard")
y = paste0(scan(file = x, what = "character", allowEscapes = F), collapse = "")
```

Unfortunately, this only works for the path currently in the clipboard, so if you are copying and pasting lots of paths into an R script, this is not a solution.  A workaround in that situation would be to paste each path into a separate text file and save it.  Then, in your main script, you could run the following

```
y = paste0(scan(file = "path1.txt", what = "character", allowEscapes = F), collapse = "")
```

You would probably need one saved file for each path.