# Passing a command with whitespace / special characters to R System Command

Tags: r, regex, escaping

I can run this command in my bash shell. The command makes a request to an API to compress an image, and gets a response from the API without issue:

```
curl https://my.api.com --user api:mypassword --data-binary @/Users/myUsername/MyDirectoryName\ \(abc\)/test/my/file.png --dump-header /dev/stdout
```

Within an R script, when I try to run the same command within R's `system` ([docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html)), like this:

```
system("curl https://my.api.com --user api:mypassword --data-binary @/Users/myUsername/MyDirectoryName\ \(abc\)/test/my/file.png --dump-header /dev/stdout", intern = T)
```

I get an error message:

`Error: '\(' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "curl https://my.api.com --user api:mypassword --data-binary @/Users/myUsername/MyDirectoryName\ \("`

I do not have control over the directory name, with its whitespace and special characters, e.g. `(` and `)`.

How do I need to change the command string passed to `system`? If this is a character escaping issue as I think it is, how would I perform the escape?

Thank you

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685737/ignore-escape-characters-backslashes-in-r-strings

Comment: Maybe @zx8754, but I'm new to R so would appreciate some more detail about what you mean. tx

Comment: I think you need to escape "escape characters", or escape "characters that are not escape but used as escape in R", hope that makes sense. I will add "regex" tag, hope that will attract better answers.

Comment: Confused because I can do something like this: system("open '/Users/myUsername/MyDirectoryName\ \(abc\)/test/my/file.png'").

Answer (score 0):

As @zx8754 suspected, escaping escape characters should help. In particular, `\` is an escape character, while things like `(` don't need to be escaped. So, escaping `\` should help:

```
system("curl https://my.api.com --user api:mypassword --data-binary @/Users/myUsername/MyDirectoryName\\ \\(abc\\)/test/my/file.png --dump-header /dev/stdout", intern = T)
```

The following shows that R is no longer unhappy about anything and prints the string correctly:

```
cat("curl https://my.api.com --user api:mypassword --data-binary @/Users/myUsername/MyDirectoryName\\ \\(abc\\)/test/my/file.png --dump-header /dev/stdout")
# curl https://my.api.com --user api:mypassword --data-binary @/Users/myUsername/MyDirectoryName\ \(abc\)/test/my/file.png --dump-header /dev/stdout
```

Comment: @Benjamin, did it help?